# JPA Entity creating only one db table

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I am developing an application but my tables excpet one are not being created by JPA. I'm not able to fix the issue. I already went over some solution on stacks but they did not work. For the cases I checked, the issue was that no tables are being created. But for me, one table is being created.

Here is my packages in eclispe IDE:

[image]

All Entity classes are stored in the com.datcarts.datcartservices.model package.

My POM file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.1</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
<groupId>com.datcarts</groupId>
<artifactId>datcartservices</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1</version>
<name>datcartservices</name>
<description>DatCarts</description>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<properties>
    <java.version>17</java.version>
</properties>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate.search</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-search-mapper-orm</artifactId>
        <version>6.1.1.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate.search</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-search-backend-lucene</artifactId>
        <version>6.1.1.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.1</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
        <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.googlecode.libphonenumber/libphonenumber -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.googlecode.libphonenumber</groupId>
    <artifactId>libphonenumber</artifactId>
    <version>8.12.46</version>
</dependency>
    
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
        <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.vladmihalcea</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-types-55</artifactId>
        <version>2.14.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
        <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-ui</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.6</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.json</groupId>
        <artifactId>json</artifactId>
        <version>20211205</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
        <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.storilabs.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>stori-sec</artifactId>
        <version>1.0_Dev</version>
        <scope>system</scope>
        <systemPath>${project.basedir}/lib/com/storilabs/security/stori-sec/1.0_Dev/stori-sec-1.0_Dev.jar
    </systemPath>
</dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <finalName>datcartservices</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

And here is a sample Entity file:

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package com.datcarts.datcartservices.model;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.Date;
import javax.persistence.Basic;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.EnumType;
import javax.persistence.Enumerated;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import javax.persistence.NamedQueries;
import javax.persistence.NamedQuery;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.persistence.Temporal;
import javax.persistence.TemporalType;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;
import javax.validation.constraints.Size;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Setter;
import lombok.ToString;

/**
*
* @author najeeba
*/
@Entity
@Table(name="offer_details")
@Getter
@Setter
@ToString
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class OfferDetails extends DateAudit  implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="offer_id")
    private Long offerId;
    
    public enum Status {
        ACTIVE,
        DISABLED,
    }
    
    private String page;
    private String section;
    private String imageUrl;
    @NotNull
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private Status status;
    @JoinColumn(name = "erp_id", referencedColumnName = "erp_id", nullable = false)
    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    private ErpDetails erpDetails;
    
    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int hash = 0;
        hash += (offerId != null ? offerId.hashCode() : 0);
        return hash;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object object) {
        // TODO: Warning - this method won't work in the case the id fields are not set
        if (!(object instanceof OfferDetails)) {
            return false;
        }
        OfferDetails other = (OfferDetails) object;
        if ((this.offerId == null && other.offerId != null) || (this.offerId != null && !this.offerId.equals(other.offerId))) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

}
```

The code deploys fine without errors (on Wildfly) but when I check postgres db, I see that only one table has been created:

[image]

And this is my application.properties file:

```
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.postgresql.Driver
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = create
logging.level.org.hibernate.SQL= DEBUG
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format_sql=true
spring.sql.init.mode=always
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.postgresql.Driver
spring.jackson.serialization.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS= false
spring.jackson.time-zone= UTC
spring.application.name=DatCart Services
spring.jpa.generate-ddl=true

# Database config
app.database.url= jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/newdats
app.database.username.key=
app.database.username.encrypted=datsuser
app.database.password.key=
app.database.password.encrypted=datspassword
```

Am I doing somethng wrong here?

Thank you for the responses!

Comment: is offer_details got created?

Comment: Any errors in console when starting the application?

Comment: @DeepeshkumarGupta No, offer_details is not created. Only order_details table is being created.

Comment: @CurssedHammer No errors in the console.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this property:

```
spring.jpa.generate-ddl=true
```

Comment: Tried adding the property, but it didnot work :(

Answer (score 0):

spring.jpa.generate-ddl=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = create

try adding the above two in properties file
also if that doesn't help
add as
spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.postgresql.Driver

Comment: Thank you for your response, tried adding all the values you listed. But still no success

Comment: can you try setting a profile and check if the properties are considered, also can you attach the DateAudit class